# How to push code from 1 TFS 2013 server to another TFS 2013 (CI) server?

Tags: tfs, synchronization

Is there any way to perform a 1 way sync from TFS 2013 server to another TFS 2013 server?

Comment: when you say sync, do you mean the whole TFS database or just some code, as per your title?

Comment: Whole database sync for the first time and only the changes later on. Either ways, I need the one-way sync is this possible?

Comment: Why do you have two servers?

Comment: One server is development and another is at client side which he wants to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is done with the TFS Integration platform if you're using TFVC on both sides, git-tfs if you're using TFVC on one side and git on the other, and just plain old git if you're using git on both sides (via multiples remotes).

TFS IP: http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/
git-tfs: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

None of these solutions are elegant. You should look for a way to use a single instance of TFS instead.